# Not able to attach jquery plugin handleCounter to dynamically created element

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, dynamically-generated

Before posting this query, I have gone through a number of posts here. But none of them help me to figure out my problem.

I'm using a jQuery plugin called handleCounter to add increment/decrement input spinners. I'm able to attach this plugin into my static elements with out any problem, but I'm not able to attach this plugin to dynamically created elements.
This is how I'm attaching this plugin to elements.`$('#id').handleCounter();` 
I tried to use the on method to monitor load events, but this does not works. Does anyone has a suggestion to handle my requirement?

Comment: if you are using a loop to create your elements then attaching the J'S code within the loop, you will have to modify your code to accommodate for that.  do a search for creating functions within a loop in JavaScript.

Comment: You need to call it after the you have appended the dynamically added element - not on page load (so in your ajax result or however they are getting appended) and also make sure the id is unique ()otherwise it will only be attached to the first element with that id)

Comment: Thanks for the response Jake and Pete.
I'm generating these new elements inside a loop. After generating this element, in the next line i tried to attach this plugin function. That didn't work.
Can you tell me how do i call this plugin function after element this generated and gave a unique id?